# get available payment method in magento store

Tags: api, payment, payment-methods, stores

how can i get list of payment methods with detaile like code,title,method and?
is it possible get available payment method in store with API ?

Comment: are you want this during checkout?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has its own api function which provides list of payment depending on the quote. Here you need to just send quote id to get the payment method list.

For example, to get the available payment methods you can use Magento SOAP API v1:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'cart_payment.list', 'quoteId');
var_dump($result);
```

See more at http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartPayment/cart_payment.list.html